# Python - Match two IDs in Dicts and return all values

Tags: python, jinja2

I am getting information from two tables in my database and putting them into two lists of dictionaries. One of these contains information on each Server and the other contains the information on each drive. The problem is that one server has many drives and I am trying to pass this to flask where it returns a table of the server info AND ALL of the drives not just the first one that matches.

```
for row in test:
    testlist.append({'Server ID': row[0], 'ServerName': row[1], 'Primary Role': row[2], 'Secondary Role': row[3],
                     'CPU-Name': row[4], 'Operating System': row[5]})

for row in drives:
    drivelists.append({'Server ID': row[0], 'Drive Mapping': row[1], 'FreeSpace': row[2], 'TotalSpace': row[3],
                       'Percentage Used': row[4]})
```

`return render_template('servers.html', basicserverinfo=testlist)`

```
     {% for info in basicserverinfo %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <h>{{ info['ServerName'] }}</h>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <div class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Server Name</dt>
            <dd> {{ info['ServerName'] }}</dd>
            <dt>Primary Role</dt>
            <dd> {{ info['Primary Role'] }}</dd>
            <dt>Secondary Role</dt>
            <dd> {{ info['Secondary Role'] }}</dd>
            <dt>CPU</dt>
            <dd> {{ info['CPU-Name'] }}</dd>
            <dt>Operating System</dt>
            <dd> {{ info['Operating System'] }}</dd>
            </div>
        </table>
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25"
                           aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{ info['Percentage Used'] }}%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I assume I need BasicServerInfo/Testlist to contain all the server info and all the drives that match the server id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm mostly replying to the title of your question since the question itself is formulated pretty confusingly.

From the title: I think what you want is to find all dicts in a list of dicts which have the same id, and get a list of them?

Assuming I am right and that is your question, this should help:

```
>>> dictlist
[{'id': 1, 'value': 'foo'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'foo'}, {'id': 1, 'value': 'bar'}]
>>> filtered_list = [d for d in dictlist if d['id']==1]
>>> filtered_list
[{'id': 1, 'value': 'foo'}, {'id': 1, 'value': 'bar'}]
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what to call it. I want to find use the ID of the first list and find all elements that match the Server ID and adds them to one big list that contains all the server info and all the drives. Sorry if it didn't word it well.

Comment: What I showed is a way to do step 2 of what you describe. You find all elements that match an ID, and you get a list from it. What remains is adding this to the other list, if I understand you correctly?